# Can we spike with a different enzyme to a SYBR Green Master Mix?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, pcr, nucleic-acids

I followed the standard SYBR Green Protocol for doing a qPCR. For which I used

- 10 uL of 1X SYBR Green Master Mix
- Forward Primer and Reverse Primer (each at a final conc. = 8.5 uM)
- Template (unknown concentration from an aptamer selection)
- Made to 20 uL with water.

Performed the PCR amplification using

1. 95 C Initial denaturation
2. 95, 68, 72 - cycled 35 times.

But, one set of sample from my aptamer selection (probably high GC content) did not amplify **at all**. I checked on an agarose gel too.

**Important Notes:**

1. My primer conc. is intentionally high - I have always amplified with such concentrations and it works perfectly using Vent Polymerase.
2. My annealing temperature is also high at 68 C because my aptamer sequences tend to be GC Rich.
3. Using Vent polymerase my amplification is very strong

On reading notes from vendors, I found out that the polymerase in the mastermix to be some variant of Taq Polymerase[1][3] (varies from vendor to vendor) and also it is known to poorly amplify GC Rich Sequences[2].

> 1. https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/4309155
> 2. https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/N8080241
> 3. https://www.fishersci.co.uk/shop/products/powerup-sybr-green-master-mix/15366158

*Hence, I wanted a suggestion from anyone working with aptamers, or if you have experience working with GC rich sequences on how I could amplify my sequences.*

Much appreciated if I could have an answer before next week.

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Can anyone help with this if you work with GC rich sequences?

Comment: I know its too late now, but this is a question well suited to ResearchGate.

Comment: I found this following answer in a Stack exchange post and seems to be helpful from the point of view of my question. If it helps anyone the following answers my question that I asked initially: 

https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/46649/33379